# JS: Pass value using Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
class Stages {

  constructor(column_param = {})   {

    this.stages = {};
    let stages_id = IHCM.RandomData.uuid();
    let orderno=1;
    this.columns = {
      "COUNTRY": "",
      "APP_ID": stages_id,
      "STAGEORDER": 1



    };
  }

}



new stages();
```

How to update Stage order as 3 ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `this.columns['STAGEORDER'] = 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you push column_param as it should use in the object variable "columns"
So if you want use it as object's start parameters it would be like this:

```
class Stages {
  constructor(column_param = {}) {
    this.stages = {};
    let stages_id = IHCM.RandomData.uuid();
    let orderno = 1;
    this.columns = Object.assign(
      {
        COUNTRY: "",
        APP_ID: stages_id,
        STAGEORDER: 1
      },
      column_param
    );
  }
}

let stages = new Stages({
  STAGEORDER: 3
});
```

But if it is a dynamic state of object you should add to your class method "updateOrder" and change it there

```
class Stages {
  constructor(column_param = {}) {
    this.stages = {};
    let stages_id = IHCM.RandomData.uuid();
    let orderno = 1;
    this.columns = {
        COUNTRY: "",
        APP_ID: stages_id,
        STAGEORDER: 1
      };
  }

  updateOrder(order) {
    this.columns.STAGEORDER = order;
  }
}

let stages = new Stages();
stages.updateOrder(3);
```

Comment: Thank you , 
let stages = new Stages({STAGEORDER: 3}); 
doesn't set the value as 3.

Comment: Of course it sets [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67nq54m3/2/) if we are talking about STAGEORDER parameter @UdhayanPonraj

Comment: if(column_param.STAGEORDER){
      this.columns.STAGEORDER = column_param.STAGEORDER;
    }